# Load Child Content with template styling in parent template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I cannot find a solution for my problem and I am pretty new to WordPress templates.

I want to load all the direct childs from my active page and load them together with the template which also uses one added image in acf. The idea is to have more than 1 static design for the loaded content.

This is the code I am using, but the_content() only loads the content field itself and not the template or the acf image.

I tried get_post but it doesn't work.

i would really appreciate if you can help me with that. :)

Best wishes,

Mike

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
 the_content();
  endwhile; 

endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is sound, but the issue is that you're not pulling any of the info in your loop.

The way WordPress works, is that on the individual template file that you are working with, you need to specify the specifics of the layout from those pages within this parent template.

How it is done is entirely dependant on the layout(s) of your child page(s), your template file structure (are you separating your templates into smaller, reusable elements (i.e. using `get_template_part()`), etc...

Essentially, you'll need to add into this template that you're working on, the additional content in the layout you require.

See the example below for a rough idea:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?>
        <div class="img-from-child">
            <img src="<?php get_field('img_src_from_child'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```